# How to configure which project to debug?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

I want to run two different Android apps from Eclipse (in two different types of Emulators) simultaneously but step through one of them, in which I've set breakpoints.

How do I configure which of the two apps is the one being debugged? It's not possible to debug both simultaneously, is it (with breakpoints in each project)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at [this image](http://hi-android.info/docs/images/debug-ddms.png), you can see that the "Devices" tab in the DDMS perspective has a "Bug" icon (the first one). If you highlight your running app (in whichever emulator it is) and click that button, debugging will become enabled for that app. If you have any breakpoints set in your code it will hit them and the debug view will open. That's the easiest way to debug a running application. I find this is the best approach because running the whole app in debug mode is slow. It's better to start debugging once you are close to where you actually want to step through.

You can also do this on an actual device, but you will need to set the `debuggable="true"` flag in the manifest, otherwise your app won't show in the list.

Comment: It seemed that _both_ apps were being debugged - they both had the bug icon in the Devices list. And the only one which had breakpoints (the second one) DID stop as expected on the breakpoint. Maybe this is new to Eclipse Indigo? Or...?

Comment: In eclipse, you can run your program in two different ways: normal and debug. It depends which button you click on the toolbar ([see here](http://code.google.com/eclipse/images/runConfigurationToolbarList.png)). The one on the left will debug it, the one on the right will run normally. For android, I really recommend that you always "plain" run them, since the debugger really slows things down quite a bit.